# Pressing two keyboard keys simultaneously (not in order)

Tags: pyautogui

I am trying to get pyautogui to press two keyboard keys at the SAME TIME(not in order). Is this possible?

I can't find anything in the documentation and have tried (press, up/down, and hotkey) with multiple syntaxes to no avail.

```
# Press and delay release of MP to start a song (This section can be removed if using for lvl 5 only
    pyautogui.keyDown('i')
    pyautogui.time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.keyUp('i')
# Start the song.
    pyautogui.keyDown('o')
    pyautogui.keyUp('o')
    pyautogui.hotkey('i', 'o')  <<<issue here, need to press 'io'.
```

Comment: What problem do you expect to appear if you generate a press of two keys very quick one after another? On an actual keyboard you can't press two keys exactly at the same time anyway ...

Comment: the issue is this bit of code is for a script in a fighting game that plays songs(one of the characters can do this)

https://github.com/calexil/bbsong

some notes require two buttons to be pressed simultaneously to make certain notes